# Formatting literal strings in Unit Tests without escaping for comparison

Tags: swift, string, unit-testing, escaping, literals

[image]

In the example above, I have a String? value of dictionary key containing unescaped backslashes. The assertion fails because the literal string I defined for comparison is escaped.

How do I define the string literal so it is unescaped in the comparison?
Or should I be escaping the dictionary value?

For example, in Perl I would define the string using single quotes or q().

I saw that there is some sort of RFC for a similar Swift solution, but what is the workaround?

Comment: Just don't escape it? Use single backslashes instead of double backslashes. The kind of string literal that you are using (`#"..."#`) allows you to do that.

Comment: Ah - this was my error, as I was editing this test, I lost track of how many literal backslashes were in the original raw string.

Answer (score 1):

Your comparison will work if you use only *one method*, not both of them:  either escape the characters (but do not use `#...#`). OR if you use `#...#`, don't escape the characters.

I.e. for a string `X4\\7`, both of the following will pass the comparison correctly:

```
"X4\\\\7"
#"X4\\7"#
```

Comment: Ah - this was my error, as I was editing this test, I lost track of how many literal backslashes were in the original raw string.